# How to overlay two images of the same width but different heights, with one fixed and the other scrolling?

Tags: css, image, scroll, overflow

I am trying to build a page that will display a .png image of a computer (with a transparent screen), which I can then layer a website screenshot behind and scroll through, to give the effect of scrolling a real website.

For example, this page, but it can be with a scrollbar instead of automatic scrolling: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/fwrd-music-band-musician-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12087239

I've actually managed to achieve the required, but I can only scroll the long website image (#instagram) when I 'inspect' the page. I assume the #laptop image is blocking the #instagram image somehow?

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#instagram {
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#laptop {
  z-index: 2;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: your  `#laptop` has a higher `z-index` than your `#instagram` so i asume that when you click on `#instagram` you are actually clicking on the other image. meaning you cant select the element you want to scroll

Comment: True! But I needed "laptop" to layer over the top of "instagram" because it is a transparent .png - the instagram needs to scroll behind it. I found a solution in the end by putting the images in separate <divs> and then putting both these <divs> within another <div>, getting rid of z-index completely and adding pointer-events: none; as suggested by the poster below :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo element with pointer events none for your laptop and then just position your scrollable background where the screen is:

```css
.laptop {
  position: relative;
  /* width and height of laptop image */
  width: 584px;
  height: 360px;
}

.laptop:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background:url(https://pngimg.com/uploads/laptop/laptop_PNG5938.png) left top no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index:2;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.background {
  /* width and height of screen */
  width:414px; 
  height:229px;
  overflow:auto;
  position:absolute;
  
  /*POsition of screen in image */
  top: 28px; 
  left:82px;
}
```

```html
<div class="laptop">
  <div class="background">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/412/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you - setting pointer-events to none worked! I put the images in separate <divs> and then put both these <divs> within another <div>, removed all z-indexing and it works lovely :)